# How to check if autokey is enabled for NTP?

Tags: linux, rhel, security, ntp, ntpd

I'm running a version of NTP that could be vulnerable to cve-2009-1252 and I want to ascertain whether it is or is not.

The vulnerability's page is https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2009-1252.

It states that hosts are vulnerable if they are running

> NTP before 4.2.4p7 and 4.2.5 before 4.2.5p74, when OpenSSL and autokey
>   are enabled,

My host's NTP version is older than 4.2.4p7 and it is running openssl. The only thing I need to ascertain is whether autokey is enabled.

OS is RHEL 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
egrep 'autokey|keysdir' /etc/ntp.conf
```

([Source](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/ConfiguringAutokeyFourTwoFour))

Comment: Ref: http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/ConfiguringAutokeyFourTwoFour